# warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I've got this simple assembly program `asm1.asm`, but I get an error when trying to compile it. This is the code

```
;--- constant variables ---
SECTION .data

    msg: db "Hello World!", 10, 0; 10: carriage return, 0: NULL end of msg (stop)

;--- dynamic variables ---
; SECTION .bss

;--- assembler code ---
SECTION .text

extern _printf
global _main                    ;
_main:                          ; void main() {
    push ebp ;basepointer       ;   /* creation of the stack */
    mov ebp, esp ;stackpointer  ;

    push msg                    ;   /* pushing memory address */
    call _printf                    ;   /* call printf */

    mov esp, ebp                ;   /* function body */
    pop ebp                     ;
    return;                     ; }
```

I get this error

```
C:\Users\David\Desktop>nasm -f elf asm1.asm
asm1.asm:23: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error
```

I'm new to assembly so I guess it's just something minor but could someone please tell me what is causing the warning?

Comment: It is just a warning, not an error. When you put a colon behind it, NASM knows that you want to create a label. When you create a label without a colon, NASM thinks: I will treat that as a label, but maybe he just misspelled a single word operation code. I will warn the user about that.
http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html

Comment: asm1.asm:23 means "this error/warning is on line **23** of the file **asm1.asm**. NASM says "I'm treating this as a label but it doesn't have a colon and doesn't appear to be an instruction" - so it's not safe to ignore warnings...

Comment: yeah, right, in this case it  is not intended to be an label, I guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's with the `return;` line?  That's not an x86 instruction name, so the assembler treats it as equivalent to `return:` and warns you about it in case that's not what you meant.

x86's return instruction is called `ret`.

In NASM syntax, a `label` without a `:` is allowed as a way to define a symbol, but it's deprecated because of the ambiguity with typoed instructions / directives, or new instruction mnemonics that this version of NASM doesn't recognize yet.  (With a `:`, you can even use instruction names as labels, like `loop:`)  `-w+orphan-labels` is on by default.

https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.1  Layout of a NASM Source Line documents this.

Comment: You are right, it should be `ret` instead... Thanks

Comment: @DavidSeres Kindly click on the checkmark at left, to mark this question as answered. That will save the rest of us from wasting time reading a question that already has an answer. And C puts an underscore in front of things, so it should be `extern _printf`, and `global _main`, and `_main:`, but technically that's a different question.

Comment: @user3386109: ELF systems (like Linux) *don't* prefix C names with `_` to create asm symbol names.  That's a 32-bit-only Windows, or MacOS (either mode), convention.  Or ancient Linux systems that still used the a.out object-file format.  The question built with `-felf`, but with NASM on a Windows prompt, so it's unclear whether they're going to link the result into a Linux executable or into a Windows one.  The calling conventions for 32-bit code are compatible enough on both systems, at least for variadic functions like printf.